# How to crossgrade debian (switch from i386 to amd64)

Tags: debian, architecture

How to switch a Debian installation from i386 to amd64 architecture (and vice versa) without reinstalling the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a detailed process given [on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading). In summary:

- ensure the target architecture is available as a foreign architecture:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
  sudo apt update
  ```
- ensure the running kernel supports both architectures:

  ```
  sudo apt install linux-image-amd64:amd64
  ```

  (and reboot)
- ensure the system is fully up-to-date:

  ```
  sudo apt upgrade
  ```
- to perform the actual crossgrade, you need to install the target architecture’s `dpkg` and related packages:

  ```
  sudo apt --download-only install dpkg:amd64 tar:amd64 apt:amd64
  sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*_amd64.deb
  ```

At this point your main architecture will be the target architecture. You can then switch packages over at your leisure; take care when crossgrading UI-related packages since the desktop environment can crash — you should do this from a terminal or at least inside a `screen` session so that a dying desktop environment doesn’t take your `apt` down with it.

In future releases of Debian, the `crossgrader` package should make this simpler.

(I have done this in the past, it is possible.)

Comment: The crossgrade tool is documented here: https://salsa.debian.org/crossgrading-team/debian-crossgrading/-/blob/master/INSTRUCTIONS.md  AFAICT, the tool was developed in the "stretch" timeframe, so it may not work exactly.  The fragile part seems to be new dependencies from dpkg/apt that must be upgraded together.